# Scheme - How to aggregate list?

Tags: scheme

I have a list of cities and I want get min of habitants. This is a list:

```
((London United-Kingdom 100000)
 (Paris France 40000)
 (Sydney Australia 350000)
 (New-York USA 1200000))
```

My code is:

```
(define (aggregate proc n lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((proc (n (car lst)) (aggregate proc n (cdr lst))))
        (else (aggregate proc n (cdr lst)))))

(aggregate max habitants cities) --> 1200000
(aggregate min habitants cities) --> 0 (should be 40000)
```

Min should be 40000. Problem is `0` in `((null? lst) 0)`, but I don't know how to rewrite my code. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Paris has more than 40.000 inhabitants :)

Comment: Habitants - How many people live there. (define (habitants x) (third x)). It give me every third element of list.

Comment: @larsmans maybe it's 19th century data.

Comment: I know it is only example.

Comment: @WillNess: Paris had a few 100k inhabitants already in the 14th century and even the bubonic plague didn't bring it down to 40k.

Comment: @Ats: sure, it's just a somewhat funny example :)

Comment: @larsmans thanks, interesting. I wonder what size Carthage was, in 3rd century BC. They say they had 5-story stone buildings (or was it brick) and two separate piping systems for drinking water and sewage. Of course it just *had* to be destroyed.

Comment: @WillNess: according to Strabo, 800.000 at its peak, and according to modern estimates, Strabo exaggerated by [at most a factor 8](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/09/01/science/relics-of-carthage-show-brutality-amid-the-good-life.html).

Comment: @larsmans thanks a lot for the link. about the factor 8 - that's just journalist pulling it out of thin air. He doesn't cite any sources. It might as well be that Strabo _lowered_ the number, to diminish the glory of the former enemy. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Note: (define habitants third) is simpler and frequently overlooked - the wonder of first-class functions...

Comment: @WillNess: actually, the factor 8 is mentioned in a quote from prof. Lawrence E. Stager of Harvard University.

Comment: @larsmans you're absolutely right. don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, minimum of 0 and 40000 is 0. See, you're using 0 as the default vaue inside `aggregate`. Either change that to 10 billion (and then your `(aggregate max ...)` won't work); or change the `aggregate` function to accept one more argument, the default value.

Like this:

```
(define (aggregate proc n lst def)
  (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) def)
        ((proc (n (car lst)) (aggregate proc n (cdr lst))))
        (else (aggregate proc n (cdr lst)))))
```

Or maybe not. Notice that you are "reducing" a binary function over a list. It only makes sense if the list is not empty. So no default value is needed here at all - it is actually wrong to use any. Instead, stop when there's only one element left in the list:

```
(define (aggregate proc n lst)
  (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) (n (car lst)))
        ((proc (n (car lst)) (aggregate proc n (cdr lst))))
        (else (aggregate proc n (cdr lst)))))
```

Pick one or the other. Notice that what the combining function `proc` produces, at must also accept as its 2nd argument. So in the 2nd variant (a.k.a. `foldr1`), it must accept two arguments of the same kind (type) and also produce a result of the same type, i.e. `proc` is  a function of type `(a -> a -> a)`. But in general, it may be different, of a type `(a -> b -> b)`, in which case only the 1st variant (a.k.a. `foldr`) will work.

Comment: It is done. I rewrite ((null? lst) 0) as ((null? (cdr lst)) (n (car lst))). It seems it works.

Comment: Thanks, I was faster. Second solution is better for me.

Comment: @Ats the truth is born in debate, of what is the saying.